# USB does not work in Windows after boot Linux

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb

I have a double boot of Windows 7 and [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) on my Dell Inspiron-15-7537

If I boot into Windows after I have been running Ubuntu, my USB ports do not work, neither the USB 2 or 3 ports. However, if I then reboot Windows once more they start working again, and will keep working until I go back into Linux again.

When in Linux they also work fine.

What could possibly be causing the USB ports to not work in Windows after running Linux?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the USB driver in Windows?

Comment: Yes, windows reports that the usb hub is fine but no connected devices are detected (until after another reboot), the connected devices do get power however

Comment: Try the Roll Back Driver option. I believe the problem is in Windows. It happened with my WiFi adapter and Roll Back option fixed it.

Comment: Try with latest Ubuntu version - currently 14.10.

Comment: @blogger This issue should be fixable by another method not a complete Distro update, I would prefer to try everything else first as this machine needs alot of packages in 14.04 for building